# Enable/Disable form controls at client side on checkbox click in MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to enable and disable all the controls on `.cshtml` from at client side. As this functionality is general for all the pages and no. of controls are not fixed, i do not want to enable and disable individual control. There must be some way by which all the controls must get disabled/enabled on checkbox click.  I am using `@HTML` helper classes to generate the input controls,following is the example for same

```
@Html.Label("lblEnableDisableTimeGen", "txt_EnableDisableTimeGen", "EnableDisableTimeGen")
@Html.CheckBox("chkEnableTimeGenProgram",true)
```

Comment: Yes,we can try with jQuery

Comment: Hey, What is the problem with this qs. who have voted it down????????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the way to do so. Here is the example

1. Define all your controls in a div. 
   e.g :

   ```
    control1....

    control2....

   </div>
   ```
2. use the script below to enable and disable all the controls within div

   ```
   function EnableDisable()
   {
      dojo.query("input, button, textarea, Select, div", 
      TimeGenProgramEnableDisable).attr("disabled", !chkEnableDisable.checked);
   }
   ```
3. Mind it here we are using DOJO toolkit

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
//Code Starts
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnDisable").click(function(e) {
        $("*").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});​
//Code Ends
```

Comment: @Uttam In this example I have used `*` to target everything but he can used any specific ones like input, etc. what is wrong with this code that someone has given -1 to this answer??????????????????

Comment: @Yoda.. No Idea why it is given -1

Comment: @Robert  are you guys aware why this answer has got -1 ?

Comment: @Uttam could you please upvote this answer? I don't think there is any issue with this answer. You just need to specify what type of control you want to disable like `input[type="xyz"]`

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery on the page:

```
function toggleChecked(status) {
   $("INPUT[type='checkbox']").each( function() {
   $(this).attr("checked",status);
})
```

This checks all checkboxes on your page. You can use it with a button's onClick, for example:

```
onclick="togggleChecked(true)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Is using javascript an option?

You could set up a click handler on the checkbox and then simply disable all the inputs on the form

Comment: I do not want to take individual control and disable it one by one,because this is a common functionality for no. of pages and controls on the pages may vary. I want it to be done at one shot

Answer (score 0):

if jquery allowed try this,,

to disable:

```
$("#parent-selector :input").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

to enable:

```
$("#parent-selector :input").removeAttr("disabled");
```

Comment: This disables the element, it doesn't check/uncheck it.